# react router relative link does not link properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

So I'm using the npm package react-router-relative (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-relative) but it doesn't seem to be switching the url properly.

Here's what my links looks like:

```
<Link to='items' className="btn btn-default submission-button">Items</Link>
<Link to='maps' className="btn btn-default submission-button">Maps</Link>
```

Here's my routing:

```
<Route path="submissions" component={SubmissionPage}>
    <Route path="items" component={ItemSubmissions}></Route>
    <Route path="maps" component={MapSubmissions}></Route>
</Route>
```

what happens is the first time I click on the link it'll link properly i.e.

```
http://localhost:3000/#/account/submissions/items
```

but when I hit it again it'll go to:

```
http://localhost:3000/#/account/submissions/items/items
```

at this point the end part will switch rather than append, but throws an error.

However, I'm trying to make the part right after 'submission' switch, i.e. `account/submissions/items` `account/submissions/maps`.

What am I doing wrong?

I've tried a non-relative link variation of this, i.e. `{this.props.location.pathname + '/items'}` but it just does the same thing.

Comment: have you tried doing `to="/items"` ?

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon that would just be `http://localhost:3000/#/items`. It's basically like command line pathing.

Comment: Import the Switch from react-router-dom and place your the route tags inside them. Does it help ?

Comment: it's abandoned package and no longer maintained but as @DayanMorenoLeon suggested you could try something like `<Link to='/submissions/items' >`

Comment: @Ozan Could you make an example? I'm trying at the moment but can't seem to get it right.

Comment: @AmrAly I want another way to link instead of doing an absolute path in the event that I decide to change the naming conventions, then I'll have to change every absolute path, which will be annoying.

Comment: you right, what react-router version  are you using?

Comment: @AmrAly I think react-router@3.0.5

Comment: you may react-router Route approach  and  `import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'` and any time you need to change route programmatically you  will use `browserHistory.push('/your/path/here')` another way you could try `this.props.router.push('/your/path/here')`

Comment: @A.Lau What was the current route when you clicked `items` link both first and second time? These are relative links, so it really matter what your current route was.

Comment: @ManasJayanth Originally, I had `http://localhost:3000/#/account/submissions` when I click item it'll go to `http://localhost:3000/#/account/submissions/items`, which works. But if I now click on map, it'll go to `http://localhost:3000/#/account/submissions/items/maps` instead of switching to `http://localhost:3000/#/account/submissions/maps`

Comment: I am assuming that at /accounts/submissions/items it rendered those two links which means those links are present in MapSubmissions component too. Am I right?

Comment: @ManasJayanth The links are actually in /accounts/submissions. /items and /maps are children of submissions.

Comment: So those links are not visible on /items or /maps?

If it were, then the behaviour `/account/submissions/items/maps` is expected since the `Link` component from `react-router-relative` you are using is written that way - they work relative to current path.

Answer (score 6):

First, let's emphasis on the concept of **relative** link.
It is a link that will bring you somewhere **depending on** where you already are.

Meaning, result will vary if you use the **same** relative link in **different** places (URLs). The direct implication is that if you want **only one** given behaviour for a relative link, you cannot use it at several places.

What happens in your case is that the **same** relative link appears for different URLs, leading to different results.

What can you do:
As pointed earlier, you could use `currentPath` props, suggested in the page you linked [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-relative#where-does-it-get-the-current-path).
The result would be something like:

```
<Link to='items' currentPath='/submissions'>Items</Link>
<Link to='maps' currentPath='/submissions'>Maps</Link>
```

Which looks like a disguised absolute path:

```
<Link to='/submissions/items'>Items</Link>
<Link to='/submissions/maps'>Maps</Link>
```

A solution for relative paths would be:

```
<Link to='../items'>Items</Link>
<Link to='../maps'>Maps</Link>
```

But keep in mind that those links, being relative, should only be displayed in one place, in your case `#/submissions/somewhere`

If you want a link that brings you to the same page regardless of the current location, you should use absolute links.

So far, I haven't come up with many uses for relative links.
Go back: `<Link to="..">Go back</Link>`
Or maybe common actions: `<Link to="./edit">Edit</Link>`

To conclude, I would say that there is no need for relative links when only one behaviour is expected. One behaviour means one route, and if you know the route, you might as well use an absolute link. Relative links should be used only when you expect different behaviours.

Answer (score 4):

I have searched for your problem and i found this useful package [react-router-relative-links](https://github.com/ryanflorence/react-router-relative-links)

To install it run in your terminal :

```
npm install react-router-relative-links react-router-apply-middleware
```

then in you routes file you will apply the middleware like so:

```
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import applyMiddlewareRouter from 'react-router-apply-middleware'
import { useRelativeLinks } from 'react-router-relative-links'


<Router history={browserHistory} render={applyMiddlewareRouter(useRelativeLinks())}>
  <Route path="submissions" component={SubmissionPage}>
    <Route path="items" component={ItemSubmissions}></Route>
    <Route path="maps" component={MapSubmissions}></Route>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

then any time you you need to add a navigate Link you can add it like so:
we will assume the current path is `localhost:8080/account/submissions`

```
<RelativeLink to='./items'>test</RelativeLink> # to localhost:8080/account/submissions/items
<RelativeLink to='./maps'>test</RelativeLink> # to localhost:8080/account/submissions/maps
```

, However it's better to use the Link component provided by [react-router](http://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/api/Redirect.html)

Comment: package is a bit old since it requires router@2. But it does work

Comment: I believe your best choice is the `<Link>` provided by react router

Comment: Mmm, probably I'll have to do regex on the current path then. I'll give you the bounty if no one answers when it expires.

Comment: I will up-vote your question to get enough attention so the professionals can help you achieving so.

Answer (score 2):

if you pass `currentPath` props to your link it will start work. otherwise, if you don't define the current path. it falls to `window.location.hash` which is not good.

```
<Link to='/items' currentPath='/submissions' className="btn btn-default submission-button">Items</Link>
<Link to='/maps' currentPath='/submissions' className="btn btn-default submission-button">Maps</Link>
```

I believe the ***npm*** package `react-router-relative` is a bit buggy. 
personally, I don't recommend you to use in production.

Comment: Yeah it's giving me a `Warning: Accessing PropTypes via the main React package is deprecated. Use the prop-types package from npm instead.`. Any other kind of relative way, maybe without react-router-relative? Maybe I should use some regex to check whether it ends in submission?

Comment: @A.Lau, my suggestion to use `react-router` which is an efficient way to define and use routes

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to find any other approach but this. Unfortunately react-router doesn't support the relative paths but the work around would be using the Switch and then generating absolute paths in your components if it is suitable for your use. You have to update your react-router to 4+ before importing the Switch method.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

<Router>
    <Switch>
    <Route path="submissions" component={SubmissionPage} />
    <Route path="items" component={ItemSubmissions} />
    <Route path="maps" component={MapSubmissions} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

But probably if I were to use only two path as you are doing which ends up being **/accounts/submissions/items** and /maps I would probably just stick with the `<Route path="/accounts/submissions/items" component={MapSubmissions} />`

P.S : I am just pointing out my approach and solution. I am not sure whether it would cause other problems or not.